# tooltip not being displayed when I use the required attribute in FireFox

Tags: html, forms

when validating my form in Firefox, it does not present me with a tooltip saying the field is required.

I have tried the following:

```
required
required="required"
required="true"
aria-required="true"

<input name="Depot" id="Depot" type="text" class="form-control 
attach-validation" aria-required="true" required="required"/>
```

I am expecting to see the tooltip saying something like 'This field is required' - just like it does in Chrome

Comment: Thats probibly just functionality of the browser itself, if you want a tooltip for other browsers you may need to design it that way.

Comment: but it works when I create a basic form and test in firefox, my forms are loaded via ajax, do you think that would be a problemo?

Comment: Try not assigning a value to the attribute per: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp